# How can I increase a number by activating a button to be able to access a function each time the button is increased?

Tags: php, javascript, function

I am trying to create a button, that whenever it is clicked (Onclick)

```
<button onClick="showUser(<?php echo $b?>)">Back</button>
```

it changes a value (number) so that the number can be retrieved by a function that will
be able to display information. Example I am calling the buttons next and back- if the button next is clicked, I want it to keep increasing it's value everytime I click it so that when it's number increases, different information will be accessed depending from that number, example when I first click the button (it would be value 1) information will be visible then when I click again it will increase to (2) and I will be able to see other information, the problem is that whenever I try to increase the value, the value increases only once.

I am doing this so that I will have information displayed and everytime the user clicks these buttons next and back, information sequentially will be shown- taken from a database.
I am using javascipt, php and sql.

Is what I am saying possible?

Comment: 100% possible.  Can we help with some specific parts?

Answer (score 1):

You could use an object, in which you set the two variables that you need to update on click:
    var obj = {
        nextClicked : 0,
        prevClicked : 0
    };

```
function buttonClick(type) {
    if(type == "prev") {
         obj.nextClicked++;
    }
    if(type == "next") {
         obj.prevClicked++
    }
}
<button type="button" onclick="buttonClick('next')">Next</button>
<button type="button" onclick="buttonClick('prev')">Prev</button>
```

Since you are using ajax, the variables would not reset, unless you refresh the page

Answer (score 0):

You could use a php [session](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) to store the "page" number you're currently on and then increase or decrease based upon which button is clicked (you could use ajax or a simple form to send the event data).

Answer (score 0):

use a hidden field to hold the value, and an onclick function to increase it and submit the form.

```
 <?

 if(!isset($_GET['count'])) {
  $count = 0;
  } else {
  $count = $_GET['count'];
  }

  ?>

   <script type='text/javascript'>
   function submitForm(x) {
     if(x == 'prev') {
     document.getElementById('count').value--;
     } else {
     document.getElementById('count').value++;
     }

     document.forms["form"].submit();
   }
   </script>

   <form action='hidfield.php' method='get' name='form'>
   <input type='hidden' name='count' id='count' value='<?php echo $count; ?>'>
   </form>

   <input type='submit' name='prev' value='prev' onclick="submitForm('prev')">
   <input type='submit' name='next' value='next' onclick="submitForm('next')">
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your webpage and refresh a few times.

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['count']++;
```

Can be tested here:

http://codepad.viper-7.com/qXdj8M