# Increment href value by one (Javascript)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

I have got a ordered list

```
<li id="prev">
    <a href="#fragment-1>Next</a>
</li>
```

I want to increment the `href` value to

```
<a href="#fragment-1">...
<a href="#fragment-2">...
<a href="#fragment-3">...
<a href="#fragment-4">...
```

When the next is clicked it should stop from 4 and return to 1 allso is it possible with javascript at all

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Give your link an `id` first to make it easier to select.

Then,

```
document.getElementById('the_id_here').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var n = e.target.href.split('-')[1] * 1 + 1;
    if (n > 4)
        n = 1;
    e.target.href = e.target.href.split('-')[0] + '-' + n;
}, false);
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/ajegaf/4#fragment-1

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you want but should be close enough to aim you in the right direction, check http://jsfiddle.net/pj28v/

```
<ul id="list"></ul>
<a href="#" id="next">Next</a>​

$(function() {

    var $list = $('#list'),
        count = 4,
        i = 0,
        cur = 0;

    for (; i < count; i++) {
        $list.append('<li><a href="#fragment' + i + '">frag' + i + '</a></li>');
    }

    $('a', $list).eq(0).css('color','red');

    $('#next').click(function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        cur++;
        if (cur >= count) cur = 0;
        $('a', $list).css('color','blue').eq(cur).css('color','red');
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

A jQuery solution:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#prev a').click(function(){

        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        var num = parseInt(href.substr(href.indexOf('-') + 1));

        if(num == 4)
        {
            num = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            num++;
        }

        $(this).attr('href', '#fragment-' + num)
    });

});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UYDdB/

Answer (score 0):

A solution similar to Delan's one but with jQuery and without the usage of a test. http://jsfiddle.net/GZ26j/

```
$('#next').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    href = $(this).attr('href');
    var n = href.split('-')[1] * 1 + 1;
    n = n%5;
    e.target.href = href.split('-')[0] + '-' + n;
});​
```

**Edit:**
This solution makes the counter start at 0 and not 1

Comment: the n%5 doesn't quite work after it gets to 4, it then starts again at zero instead of one.

Answer (score 0):

use a hidden field to hold the value, and an onclick function to increase it and submit the form. SEE: [How can I increase a number by activating a button to be able to access a function each time the button is increased?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10127399/how-can-i-increase-a-number-by-activating-a-button-to-be-able-to-access-a-functi/10127674#10127674)

```
 <?

 if(!isset($_GET['count'])) {
  $count = 0;
  } else {
  $count = $_GET['count'];
  }

  ?>

   <script type='text/javascript'>
   function submitForm(x) {
     if(x == 'prev') {
     document.getElementById('count').value--;
     } else {
     document.getElementById('count').value++;
     }

     document.forms["form"].submit();
   }
   </script>

   <form action='hidfield.php' method='get' name='form'>
   <input type='hidden' name='count' id='count' value='<?php echo $count; ?>'>
   </form>

   <input type='submit' name='prev' value='prev' onclick="submitForm('prev')">
   <input type='submit' name='next' value='next' onclick="submitForm('next')">
```