# I need next and previous for my dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have many links in my page, i need to show all that in one line but space is not enough so i need next and previous buttons.

```
<div style="width:400px;">
<ul id="links">
            <li><a href="#7a">1234564544</a></li>
            <li><a href="#7b">1234564544</a></li>
            <li><a href="#7c">1234564544</a></li>
            <li><a href="#8a">1234564544</a></li>
            <li><a href="#8b">1234564544</a></li>
            <li><a href="#8c">1234564544</a></li>
            <li><a href="#9a">1234564544</a></li>
            <li><a href="#9b">IX B</a></li>
            <li><a href="#9c">IX C</a></li>
            <li><a href="#10a">X A</a></li>
            <li><a href="#10b">X B</a></li>
            <li><a href="#10c">X C</a></li>
</ul></div>
```

Please help me...

Comment: To clarify: you don't want scrollbar and instead would prefer to use `<<` and `>>` button?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10138387/increment-href-value-by-one-javascript/10138542#10138542 see the example I posted it does that (but also generates the list which is the logic you don't need but should be good enough to show you the process

Comment: i was used jCarousel but it's not working properly for my dynamic content

Comment: Your links are for different contents on the same page?

Comment: @Sam edited my answer for jCarousel-less script

Answer (score 3):

[jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/) is a plugin that might just does what you want.

If you'd like to implement it yourself, you could use a bit of jQuery, and call `animate()` on click event for the `<<` and `>>` buttons

Something to get you started:

http://jsfiddle.net/j37RK/6/

This way you can just inject your dynamic content and it should still work, please give it a go :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this JCarousal for your requirement :- http://www.baijs.nl/tinycarousel/

Answer (score 0):

with [Sweet Pages](http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2010/05/sweet-pages-jquery-pagination-solution/demo.html) you can do that .